# How do I assign a tuple of String to a cell's text?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am making a grouped table and it is showing this error:

> cannot assign value of type '(String, String)' to type String.

I am using Xcode 8.3.3.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource  {
    let people = [
                    ("Purnima Yadav", "New Delhi"), ("Gitesh Yadav", "Toronto"), ("Vidhi Yadav", "Chicago")]
    let videos = [
                    ("Android app Development", "74 videos"), ("C++ for Beginners", "87 videos"), ("Java", "142 videos"), ("Python Programming", "63 videos"), ("Web design", "68 videos")
    ]

    //return int , how many rows
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        if section == 0 {
            return people.count
        } else {
            return videos.count
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            var (personName, personLocation) = people[indexPath.row]
            cell.textLabel?.text = personName
        } else {
            var (videoTitle, videoDesc) = videos[indexPath.row]

            cell.textLabel?.text = videoTitle
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

I am getting error at:

```
cell.textLabel?.text = personName
```

Comment: Why are you creating arrays of tuples? Why are you casting them to an array of `Any`? Why does the first tuple of `videos` only have one value when the rest have two values?

Comment: Why are you checking for iOS 2.0? It's been 11 years since any device used iOS 2.0. You shouldn't attempt to support anything less than iOS 11 for any new app development. Also note that any new apps going to the store must be built with Xcode 10.1 or later so you need to upgrade sooner than later.

Comment: that was by mistake.

Comment: Now I'm getting a error in `cell.textLabel?.text = personName` . It says _cannot assign value of type '(String, String)' to type (String)_.

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve your issue by giving a specific type to your `videos` object as `[(String, String)]` which is an `Array` of `Tuples` and your declaration will look like:

```
let videos: [(String, String)] = [("Android app Development", ""), ("C++ for Beginners", "87 videos"), ("Java", "142 videos"), ("Python Programming", "63 videos"), ("Web design", "68 videos")]
```

Here you also need to update your `("Android app Development")` with `("Android app Development", "")` to satisfy your type casting.

Comment: FYI - `("Android app Development")` is a tuple. It's just not a tuple of two value like the others.

Answer (score 1):

The tuple `("Android app Development")` does not have a second set. It should be `("Android app Development", "")`. 
Also you casted your array of tuples to an array of `[Any]`. Just remove it.

Comment: that was by mistake.. and it's not `[Any]` type